# Parse <img> tag in angular model property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular to render some HTML content:

```
<p class="description" ng-model="listing.Description"></p>
```

When it renders the content it shows images within the text which is fine.

Now, I want to find the `<img>` tags and remove the content within it, so it will only render text.

For example:

```
<p>Hi this is Peter</p>
<img src=jfj"></img>    <!--------- This line should be removed -->
<span>Span 4 </span>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your question..

Comment: I am getting Html content from a service, It renders the text and some images but I dont want images to be shown, so I want to retrieve the content without images. It seems I need to remove <img> tags from there

Comment: Share a piece of your HTML content please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter and some regex to strip the `<img>` tag. The example below relies on there being an opening and closing tag.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('removeImg', function($sce) {
    return function(input) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(input.replace(/\<img.*img\>/gi, ''));
    }
  })
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.listing = {
      Description: '<p>Hi this is Peter</p><img src=jfj"></img><span>Span 4 </span>'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as dc">
  <p class="description" ng-bind-html="dc.listing.Description | removeImg"></p>
</div>
```